# Why is the current source type/waveform influencing the ac analysis in ltspice?

Tags: ltspice, bode-plot

As I understood the ltspice `.ac`  analysis, it would linearize the circuit and solve it with an AC stimulus in the source marked with "AC 1" ( which then would determine the reference level)

This works about as expected in this circuit where the current source is a sine, and also unsurprisingly nothing in the resulting plot changes when you change the sine parameters :
[image]

However, when I do the same for when the current source is a pulse, the result is not only not at the level I would expect, also the plot shape is not correct at all.

[image]

Is that related to the DC operating point being different?

Comment: Would the square generator not used in ac analysis ?